# Error message being displayed before correct output shown in Java

Tags: java

I am implementing a try catch block to confirm a file exists before reading data from the file, then using that data to print out a menu to eventually run a menu-driven application. It appears as though I am correctly reading from the file, however, when I run the driver class, it displays the error message contained in the catch block before it correctly displays the output menu as desired.

```
public static void main(String[] args)

{
    try
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("concerts.txt"));
        ConcertEvent concert1 = new ConcertEvent(input);
        ConcertEvent concert2 = new ConcertEvent(input);
        ConcertEvent concert3 = new ConcertEvent(input);


        System.out.println("Redbird Concert Hall");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Please choose your concert:");
        System.out.println("1. " + concert1.getBandName());
        System.out.println("2. " + concert2.getBandName());
        System.out.println("3. " + concert3.getBandName());
        System.out.println("4. Quit");
        System.out.println();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: File Not Found");
    }
```

I attached the constructor used in creating the three instances of ConcertEvent

```
public ConcertEvent(Scanner input)
{
    try
    {
        bandName = input.nextLine();
        showCapacity = input.nextInt();
        ticketPrice = input.nextDouble();
        input.nextLine();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: file not found");
    }

}
```

desired output:

```
Redbird Concert Hall

Please choose your concert:
1. Maroon 5
2. One Direction
3. Pearl Jam
4. Quit
```

actual output:

```
Error: file not found (Exception found in the catch statement of the 
Redbird Concert Hall

Please choose your concert:
1. Maroon 5
2. One Direction
3. Pearl Jam
4. Quit
```

I realize it's probably not correct to have the try catch block in the constructor, however when I remove the try catch block, the actual output changes to...

Error: File Not Found (the exception found in the catch statement of the main method)

Comment: You're not capturing any details about the actual exception that took place. Instead of just `System.out.println("Error: file not found");`, also print the stack trace `e.printStackTrace()` so you can see where the problem is.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: And please don't catch the Exception class instances directly. For example, here you should only be concerned about catching `FileNotFoundException`s.

Answer (score 1):

The `catch` block triggered is the one in your `ConcertEvent` constructor, and it may be that the file cannot be found or is not accessible, or etc. (you won't know until you print the stack trace).

If you want your prompt output to take place before any file operations, just move it to before the `try` block in your `main` method.

Also, as Chandranshu mentions, catching specific exceptions will help you nail down the issue.

Finally, it doesn't make much sense to have your `main` method stating a `try`/`catch` statement for a constructor that also has a `try`/`catch` statement, reasonably for the same `Exception`(s).

Either `throw` the `Exception`s in the constructor, or remove the `try`/`catch` in your `main` method.

For instance, as `FileNotFoundException` is a checked exception, you could `throw` it in your constructor (and **must** declare a `throws` statement in its signature), then `catch` it in `main`, then `printStackTrace` in your `catch` statement in `main`).